# The first Firemonkey form shown in an iOS App isn't drawn completely

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

[image]I'm using Firemonkey to create an iOS App. The first form shown (Main Menu) seems to be drawn uncomplete on both simulator and device. For example I get a black bar at the bottom instead of the background color. Maybe the form-sizing is the problem here. 
All other forms I'm loading on button clicks are drawn completely.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Edit: Screenshot attached. The lower black area is supposed to be also gray.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot illustrating the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I just found a workaround myself. I placed a panel with alignment "client" on the form and included all other controls into this panel. I'll reproduce the problem and post a screenshot for you.

Comment: Thanks.  No idea of the cause, but if it happens with a simple app maybe you can [file it as a QC bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx), with the example.  On another note: you teach people how to fly??

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's going to be a 'Quiz' with the official questions of the licence test in Germany. So you can train before you really take the test. Just like preparing for a driving licence ;)

Comment: I'm planning on taking a few lessons in July with a club near Köln!  Depending on how far I go, I might find your app rather useful... do you have a link?

Comment: It's not in the AppStore yet. I'll post a link here as soon as its available ;)

Comment: AS you requested, here is the link to the finished app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ul-trainer/id537903384?l=de&ls=1&mt=8